# How do I setup DI for EntityFramework 6 on ASP.NET webapi (not core)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, entity-framework-6, .net-4.8

I'm working on an ASP.NET webapi app targeting .NET Framework 4.8.1.
I've setup DI using *Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection*.
I setup DI for all controller, Serilog and MediatR.
All that works fine.

Now I need to setup DI for EF6 but I can't seem to find any examples. All the examples I have found are for ASP.NET core which rely on the build in support for DI and EF core.

Does anyone have some example for setting up DI for EF6 on ASP.NET webapi targeting framework 4.8.1.